# Relative Paths in Javascript in an external file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, css, path

So I'm running this javascript, and everything works fine, except the paths to the background image. It works on my local ASP.NET Dev environment, but it does NOT work when deployed to a server in a virtual directory.

This is in an external .js file, folder structure is

```
Site/Content/style.css
Site/Scripts/myjsfile.js
Site/Images/filters_expand.jpg
Site/Images/filters_colapse.jpg
```

then this is where the js file is included from

```
Site/Views/ProductList/Index.aspx

$("#toggle").click(function() {
    if (left.width() > 0) {
        AnimateNav(left, right, 0);
        $(this).css("background", "url('../Images/filters_expand.jpg')");
    }
    else {
        AnimateNav(left, right, 170);
        $(this).css("background", "url('../Images/filters_collapse.jpg')");
    }
});
```

I've tried using `'/Images/filters_collapse.jpg'` and that doesn't work either; however, it seems to work on the server if I use `'../../Images/filters_collapse.jpg'`.

Basically, I want have the same functionallity as the ASP.NET tilda -- `~`.

**update**

Are paths in external .js files relative to the Page they are included in, or the actual location of the .js file?

Comment: Is your application directory different in development compared to the server? Visual Studio's in built web server sets the default path to '/' if your server has say '/MyApp' you might have inconsistent behaviour. Try setting your visual studio path to '/MyApp'

Comment: That is exactly the problem! Depending on where the virtual directory is located, I don't want to have to update my javascript every time I switch from dev to production...

Comment: Seems like this, http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2009/02/18/asp.net-mvc-tip-47-ndash-using-resolveurl-in-an-html.aspx, is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using javascript to dynamically change the background image of a div tag. I'd like to avoid putting the code back into the master page file, since it's much more clean its own external .JS file...

Comment: There is nothing like ~ for javascript. You could have a helper function in JS. For example you would call MyJs.Url('Images/filters.jp') and this prefix your virtual directory and return the string. This way you will only need to change it one location on deploy.

Comment: Are paths in external .js files relative to the Page they are included in, or the actual location of the .js file?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

### JavaScript file paths

When in script, **paths are relative to displayed page**

to make things easier you can print out a simple js declaration like this and using this variable all across your scripts:

Solution, which was employed on **StackOverflow** around Feb 2010:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var imagePath = 'http://sstatic.net/so/img/';
</script>
```

If you were visiting this page around 2010 you could just have a look at **StackOverflow's html source**, you could find this badass one-liner [formatted to 3 lines :) ] in the `<head />` section

Comment: I ended up doing this, except I use Url.Content to generate the value for `imagePath.` Thanks!

Comment: Haha I did the same thing, then came back and read your comment nate.

Comment: This works but it is also definetively a workaround, not a proper solution. @schory's answer gave me the solutions to OP's problem.

Comment: This doesn't work on test/dev machines. Why would you hardcode the path?

Comment: you can always output your domain name or localhost path based on your configuration (dev/prod) dynamically

Comment: I used `Url.Content("~")` to get the _Application_ root. hth

Comment: I also like to do `var imagePath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/"`

Answer (score 48):

get the location of your javascript file during run time using jQuery by parsing the DOM for the 'src' attribute that referred it:

```
var jsFileLocation = $('script[src*=example]').attr('src');  // the js file path
jsFileLocation = jsFileLocation.replace('example.js', '');   // the js folder path
```

(assuming your javascript file is named 'example.js')

Comment: $("#FkngDiv").load(jsFileLocation+"../FkngFolder/FkngPage.aspx") Worked like a charm for me. I'm using it this way to go back one folder level and then I just point to my desired path.

Comment: very good answer. I'd change the `.replace` expression to `jsFileLocation.replace(/example\.js.*$/, '')` in case there's a query string like a version number after the `.js`

Comment: You dear sir, are my newest hero! Used this solution to find my css path on the server in an ASP.NET MVC Application, which is dynamically loaded from a folder one way sideways from my javascript folder...

Answer (score 27):

A  proper solution is using a css class instead of writing src in js file.
For example instead of using:

```
$(this).css("background", "url('../Images/filters_collapse.jpg')");
```

use:

```
$(this).addClass("xxx");
```

and in a css file that is loaded in the page write:

```
.xxx {
  background-image:url('../Images/filters_collapse.jpg');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I'm using a non-css attribute. For example: `<img src="/codes/imgs/a.png">`. I can't set this src attribute by css.

Answer (score 14):

Good question.

- When in a CSS file, URLs will be relative to the CSS file.
- When writing properties using JavaScript, URLs should always be relative to the page (the main resource requested).

There is no `tilde` functionality built-in in JS that I know of. The usual way would be to define a JavaScript variable specifying the base path:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  directory_root = "http://www.example.com/resources";

</script>
```

and to reference that root whenever you assign URLs dynamically.

Comment: Hard coding the root doesn't work on your dev box, test server, etc.

Answer (score 5):

For the MVC4 app I am working on, I put a script element in _Layout.cshtml and created a global variable for the path required, like so:

```
<body>

<script>
    var templatesPath = "@Url.Content("~/Templates/")";
</script>

<div class="page">
    <div id="header">

       <span id="title">

        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="main">


        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I used pekka's pattern.
I think yet another pattern.

```
<script src="<% = Url.Content("~/Site/Scripts/myjsfile.js") %>?root=<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Site/images") %>">
```

and parsed querystring in myjsfile.js.

[Plugins | jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following syntax to enjoy the luxury of asp.net tilda ("~") in javascript

```
<script src=<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/MasterPages/assets/js/jquery.js")%>></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this to work for me.

```
    <script> document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="' + window.location.protocol + "//" +     
    window.location.host + "/" + 'js/general.js?ver=2"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

between script tags of course... (I'm not sure why the script tags didn't show up in this post)...

Comment: I don't know why your answer got downvote. This is what worked for me after hours of struggle... (Y)

Comment: I think because this points to http://servername/js rather than http://servername/applicationname/js,  which I think is no different from "/js"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `runat="server"` and and to assign an ID for it, then specify the absolute path like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" runat="server" id="myID" src="~/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>]`

From the codebehind, you can change the src programatically using the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This works well in ASP.NET webforms.

Change the script to

```
<img src="' + imagePath + 'chevron-large-right-grey.gif" alt="'.....
```

I have a master page for each directory level and this is in the Page_Init event

```
  Dim vPath As String = ResolveUrl("~/Images/")
    Dim SB As New StringBuilder
    SB.Append("var imagePath = '" & vPath & "'; ")
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "LoadImagePath", SB.ToString, True)
```

Now regardless of whether the application is run locally or deployed you get the correct full path

```
http://localhost:57387/Images/chevron-large-left-blue.png
```