# Paths with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, path, relative-path

Before closing the `body` tag of my `first.php` page, I want to load `pop.html` by javascript. Both are sitting on the root folder of my `public_html` directory.

By using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#modal-layer" ).load( "pop.html" );
</script>
```

It works when I access `first.php` directly:

`http://www.example.com/first.php`

But since I'm using a pretty URL for this page, such as:

`http://www.example.com/pretty/first/`

`pop.html` won't load because of the path.

How can I load it? the weird thing is that I even tried an absolute path:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#modal-layer" ).load( "http://www.example.com/pop.html" );
</script>
```

But even this didn't work.

Note that I need a universal solution rather than a path form that will go up only one level, as some of my pages have pretty urls that go deeper than one level.

Comment: Open your developer console, and report the error here...

Comment: is the pretty url (`http://www.example.com/pretty/first/`) on the same domain as the original (`http://www.example.com/first.php`) url?

Comment: @BillyMoon You are right, actually problem was with a path inside `pop.html`. Though since I saw [this thread ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file) I thought maybe my problem was related to that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution is probably an absolute path with no scheme or domain part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#modal-layer" ).load( "/pop.html" );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem was actually somewhere else but this is indeed what I should use nonetheless.