# Using jeditable and getting TypeError: $(...).editable is not a function, what to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

So I'm trying to use [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin to get some editable text and by now I've almost repeated the example from the plugin homepage, what I have is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.mini.js"></script>
<div class="edit">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.edit').editable('/meh.php');
    });
</script>
```

And I keep getting the

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).editable is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess would be that the plugin is just horribly outdated. The demo on the plugin's page uses jQuery 1.3.2, which was released back in 2009. You're using jQuery version 1.12.0 which was released back in January this year.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with code. If you're hosting this code on a https website, browser might deny loading your jeditable file because it's on http.

Comment: https://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.mini.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK) .. this might be the reason

Comment: @JamesDonnelly changed jquery link to version 1.3.2, nothing happened :D Is there any newer version of this plugin? Can't google anything useful

Comment: @RinoRaj but when I go on http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.mini.js everything loads perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a working demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.edit').editable('/meh.php');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.jeditable.mini.js"></script>
<div class="edit">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

**But same code is not working here**

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/xFW8t/870/)

In fiddle : the server responded with a status of 404 (OK) .. this might be the reason

Comment: weeeeellp, and how could I solve this? find the plugin source stored on https instead of http?

Comment: @Coffee You can download this and keep it locally and give a relative path

Comment: how could I load it from local folder? Putting path in src gives "GET http://localhost:8000/js/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js is not found"

Comment: @Coffee you should give relative path. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file