# In yii2 how to refer a external csv file into java script?

Tags: javascript, charts, yii2

As it is yii2, i cannot refer external file.
my index file in view folder code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    "temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file
    {}          // options
  );
</script>
```

i need to call my temperatures.csv in the same view folder, i don't know how to give the path, any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative Paths in Javascript in an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file)

Comment: No, its a model view and controller method and so we need to define differently, its not common for yii2 we need something different to refer the path.

Comment: @paviTHRAN you can try giving ` "<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/path/". "temperatures.csv" ?>" ` in javascript

Comment: @indrashastri Its also not working.

Comment: pavi THARAN please check if you want the file path in url or directory path, if url then create a url of the file and give url in comment else try `dirname(dirname(__DIR__))'.'/path/tempratures.csv'`

Answer (score 0):

The folder with view templates is not directly accessible in yii2 so there is no way to refer the csv file there from javascript.

The most simple way to deal with it is to **put the csv file in the `web` folder**.

For example you can put your csv file to `web/data` folder. To get the url for the file you can use url helper.

```php
\yii\helpers\Url::to('@web/data/temperatures.csv');
```

It's better to use the url manager to get the url because it will take care of handling the base url for you, that might be different in different environments. For example final url will probably be `/data/temperatures.csv` in production but it can be `/web/data/temperatures.csv` in development.

Another option is to **make action that will send the file**.

In that case you can leave the `temperatures.csv` where it is. You need to make a new action in your controller, for example `getTemperatures`.

```php
public function actionGetTemperatures()
{
    $file = \Yii::getAlias('@app/views/controller/temperatures.csv');
    return \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
}
```

Then you will use the url of this action in javascript.

```php
\yii\helpers\Url::to(['controller/get-temperatures']);
```

The advantage of this solution is, that it allows you to control whether the user is allowed to access the file.

Comment: It is also not working, the values in csv files are not formatting correctly to a javascript variable