# Working with Relative Paths - Create variable name for path?

Tags: javascript, html, css, path

I am working on html/javascript and found these imports prone to confusion:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../_GUI/css/sample.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../_GUI/css/button.css">
```

Multiple `../../` in code doesn't really look nice and looks confusing.

Is there any way I can make something like a variable where in:

```
GUI = ../../../../_GUI ?
```

I also checked absolute paths but that would not be so reliable since root folder may change.

Help~

Comment: Did you try with the  '~' symbol ? For example: ~/YourFileName/sample.css. This will find your 'sample.css' no matter whatever the case provided the project should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple declaration like below and use that variable all over the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var stylePath = 'http://_GUI/css/sample.css';
</script>
```

And also you can use jQuery to get the file location in runtime like below.

```
var fileLocation = $('script[src*=sample]').attr('src'); 
fileLocation = fileLocation.replace('sample.css', '');
```

Go to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file) to learn more about this.